# Why would I be unable to type input when using a using serial console in Linux?

Tags: linux, console, serial-port

I have a Slackware machine with an RJ45 serial port and I'd like to have a serial console on it. So I have connected it up to another machine running Hyperterminal.  I can only get output on the console and cannot send any input back to the device. The login prompt appears, and if I set the `lilo.conf` flags I can see all of the kernel messages, but I can't type anything in.

I have this line in `/etc/inittab` on the machine itself:

```
s1:12345:respawn:/sbin/agetty -L ttyS0 38400 vt100
```

I have the same problem on ubuntu server 14.04.  What could be causing this?

Comment: Can You describe setup more precisely: what program are You using to connect to this serial port (and what settings)? Did You checked the cable? Is cable genuine or You did it yourself (does it work with any other hardware)? I'm asking because it is a chance of broken wire.

Comment: I'm using putty and hyperterminal. i changed /etc/inittab only. I can view login prompt. if i configure lilo.conf, all kernel messages is shown too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replaced cable and problem solved!